# Istio response compression filter warning

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

For some reason, Istio 1.8.1 stopped accepting gzip filter for Envoy.

`Warning: Envoy filter: can't unmarshal Any nested proto type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.compressor.v3.Compressor: unknown field "response_direction_config" in envoy.extensions.filters.http.compressor.v3.Compressor`

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: gzip
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: istio-ingressgateway
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
      match:
        context: GATEWAY
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: envoy.http_connection_manager
              subFilter:
                name: envoy.router
      patch:
        operation: INSERT_BEFORE
        value:
          name: envoy.filters.http.compressor
          typed_config:
            "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.compressor.v3.Compressor
            remove_accept_encoding_header: true
            response_direction_config:
              common_config:
                min_content_length: 100
                content_type:
                  - '*/*'
            compressor_library:
              name: for_response
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.compression.gzip.compressor.v3.Gzip
                memory_level: 9
                window_bits: 15
                compression_level: 9
```

Comment: It stopped working after upgrade to 1.8.1 or it just stopped working? If after upgrade what  was the previous version?

Comment: I have upgraded from 1.8.1 to 1.8.2 and the first time when I created `EnvoyFilter` everything was fine and later it started to fail again with the same warning message and compression stopped working,

Comment: Now it seems like it randomly fails.

Comment: Seeams like a bug. I would suggest opening a bug ticket on https://github.com/istio/istio

Comment: Bug report: https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/31510